# Emulador flutter queda en blanco

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

A la hora de correr el emulador de flutter, la aplicación queda en blanco. La porción de código que no permite la correcta ejecución es la siguiente:

```
async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Y se encuentra dentro del método main:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que sin esta porción de código, el programa no se puede conectar con la base de datos de Firebase, lo cual es muy importante para dicha aplicación.

Comment: No creo que esas líneas sean el problema la verdad, no quiero generalizar, pero creo que la gran parte de las aplicaciones desarrolladas con flutter usan al menos la primera línea de código.

Comment: ¿La consola muestra algún error?